# Compounding return in ETF doesn't exist

Tags: compounding-interest

If I just spend 10,000$ to buy an S&P 500 ETF today, according to the media I'm getting compounding returns if I just leave it there for a long time (20 years for example).

But the 10,000$ I'm spending gives me a corresponding unit amount of the ETF. Let's say 10,000$ gives me 700 units of this ETF. Then let's say for the next two decades, every year the S&P 500 increases by 10%.

So 10%*20 = 200%. After 20 years, my 700 units of ETF have risen in price by 200%. But this is not compounding.

In a savings account with 10% interest per year, 1000 in year one becomes 1100 at the end of year one, and in year two it is 10%*1100. This is compounding interest.

The ETF just rises or falls in price per unit. There is no compounding here. So why does the media and the internet lie about stock market compounding?

Comment: If after 20 years, the price has risen by 200%, then by definition the CAGR is not 10% but only 5.65%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every year it increases 10% from the *previous* year.

So first year you got 110%, but the next year: 121%. Then 133%. And so on. That's compounding. So after 10 years your compounded total would be 259%. After 20 - 653%.

Comment: Pedantically: the CAGR is the single rate that would give the same ending value *as if* every year grew X% from the previous year, although the growth actually varied widely.  (Admittedly, the erroneous assumption of uniform growth was already posed in the question)

Comment: Well yeah, I didn't mean to imply that stocks are guaranteed to grow lineary, I was just trying to clarify the misunderstanding of applying the average past performance in this case

Answer (score 3):

A stock ETF or mutual fund, or for that matter individual stocks, do not have the concept of compounding.  While they do have the the ability to have capital gains and dividends, but that generally is only a small part of the increase in value. Most of the growth is in the change in value of the companies.

It seems natural to look at the past change in value and  express it in a percent annual growth. This lets you compare this investment with other investments.

> Then let's say for the next two decades, every year the S&P 500
> increases by 10%.

In your example it didn't grow 10% every year, the value grow over the 20 years, and the results can be modeled with a 10% growth. Some of those years the results were far better, and other years they were far worse.

The issue comes when somebody says I can expect the value to grow x% every year, just because when looking back over the decades the results can be modeled with a x% annual growth rate.  Next year the best performing fund can drop 20% even though it rose 30% this past year.

Comment: The "change in value of the companies" *is* capital gain.  Perhaps in the previous sentence you meant to write *distributed* capital gain?  (Or worse, return of capital)  While the fund can't distribute a capital gain without realizing it, it is possible to have realized-by-undistributed gains, as well as unrealized gains, both of which grow the NAV of the ETF.

Answer (score 1):

The statement about compounding was easier to see when more of the benefit of owning stock came in the form of dividends. Reinvesting stock dividends is like leaving your bank account dividends in the bank; if the stock's trading value doesn't change at all, reinvesting a 5% dividend means you own (1.05)^N times the initial value after N years.

But on average, the price of stocks also goes up.

Across the entire market, the historical average annual rate of return from price growth and dividends combined is usually quoted as "about 8% per year"; you can websearch "market rate of return" for more details about how that has varied over time. IN THE LONG RUN, ON AVERAGE, SUFFICIENTLY DIVERSIFIED investments in the market do indeed behave as if they are compounding at that rate. Example: Based on today's value, the growth in my own investments over the past 5 years, through the Covid boom and bust and recovery, is equivalent to their having grown at a compounded 8.3% per year. Over three decades, it's closer to 8.5%. (I'm not doing anything fancy, just index funds.)

Of course that isn't guaranteed as a bank account would be, and in the shorter term booms and busts and random shifts will occur. If you can tolerate the risks and wait out those swings, you will -- most of the time, on average -- get better return from the stock market than from a bank account.

(Note that one of the reasons for keeping a year's worth of spending in forms other than investments is specifically so you can avoid having to draw money out of your investments when the market is misbehaving, and thus avoid turning "on paper" losses into real lost money.)